# Is it possible to use (CSS) transitions when using element.requestFullscreen in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, html5-fullscreen

I found no documentation about it, has anyone tried?

i tried this CSS:

```
img{
    transition: all .6s linear;
}
```

But I see no transition happening